# Can not debug play framework 2.6.x java

Tags: playframework-2.6

I am new to Play, I have installed playframwork 2.6. I used to be able to debug the project but now I can not.  I have tried many projects but I can not debug.

When I issue the command sbt run, then there is no problem:

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

But when I issue the command `sbt -jvm-debug 9999`, then the output to the console is as follows:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
[info] Loading settings for project play-new-build from plugins.sbt,scaffold.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/erlendurag/projects/play-new/project
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to play-new (in build file:/home/erlendurag/projects/play-new/)
[info] sbt server started at local:///home/erlendurag/.sbt/1.0/server/80df831136abccd57227/sock
[play-new] $
```

But the AkkaHttpServer is not starting? By using the netstat command I see that java is listening to the port.  But if I open localhost:9000 there is nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for Using the SBT console https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlayConsole

There is this line of code:

You can ask Play to start a JPDA debug port when starting the console. You can 
then connect using Java debugger. Use the sbt -jvm-debug  command to do 
that:

`$ sbt -jvm-debug 9999`

But if I want to run the AkkaHttpServer also then the right command is:

```
sbt run -jvm-debug 9999
```

This was wery confusing for me!

But in these Play Framework Tutorials gave me the answer.

```
sbt run -jvm-debug 9999
```

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYPFxrXyK0Bx9SBkNhJr1e2-NlIq4E7ED